# Alias in Clojure's require function doesn't work

Tags: java, jdbc, clojure

I would like to use clojure.java.jdbc to run some sql queries. The repl gave me CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: jdbc

the code and the exception is

```
  (require `[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])
  (def db-spec {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" :subprotocol "mysql" :subname   "//localhost:3306/foo" :user "root" :password "1234"})
  (jdbc/query db-spec ["select * from client"])
  => nil
  => #'gaga.core/db-spec
  CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: jdbc, compiling:   (C:\Users\User\.IdeaIC14\system\tmp\form-init1177514063701175563.clj:3:1)
```

It looks to me that the alias definition in require function is not working. If I use the full name clojure.java.jdbc to replace the jdbc alias in above code, everything seems to work:

```
(require `[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])
(def db-spec {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" :subprotocol "mysql" :subname "//localhost:3306/foo" :user "root" :password "1234"})
(clojure.java.jdbc/query db-spec ["select * from client"])
=> nil
=> #'gaga.core/db-spec
=> ({:birthday #inst "1990-09-08T14:00:00.000-00:00", :gender 0, :addressid 1, :mobile "13890879283", :idnum "31090818790987", :idtype 0, :name "xiaomao", :version 0, :id 1})
```

my project.cli is below

```
(defproject gaga "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
            :description "FIXME: write description"
            :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
            :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
                      :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
            :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.6"] [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.35"]]
            :main ^:skip-aot gaga.core
            :target-path "target/%s"
            :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: a var would never actually print like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so basically as i tested it's syntax error in require
you have to use

```
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])
```

means use '(Apostrophe) instead of `(Acute)